# Converting a datatable to JSON results in duplicated data

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, datatable

I'm using the asp.net web API in angularjs, I'm calling the Web API method which returns the datatable, but there are then twice as many items; e.g. if datatable had 2 rows then response has 4 rows.

In that example, the method should return only 2 rows, but in client side it appears with all items duplicated in the array.

How can I correctly retrieve it without getting the duplicated data?

Webmethod which returns 2 rows

//// GET api/

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{            
long id = 791;
DateTime dFromDate = DateTime.MinValue;
DateTime dToDate = DateTime.MinValue;

DataSet ds_jobs = DAL.Jobs.FilterJobByRecruiterId_new("", dFromDate, dToDate, "all", id, 1, 2, true, 2);

if (ds_jobs == null || ds_jobs.Tables.Count == 0 || ds_jobs.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

return Request.CreateResponse<IEnumerable<DataRow>>(HttpStatusCode.OK, ds_jobs.Tables[0].AsEnumerable());  
}
```

And AngularJS code which consumes the above method

```
   var recruiter = angular.module('recruiter', []);

    recruiter.service('jobsService', ['$http', function ($http) {


    this.getAllJobsByRecruiterId = function () {
    $http.get('http://localhost:51315/api/recruiter').success(function (result) {
    return result[0].Table;
    });
    };

    } ]);



recruiter.controller('jobsController', ['$scope', 'jobsService', function ($scope,     jobsService) {


var recId = 791;

$scope.Jobs = jobsService.getAllJobsByRecruiterId();

} ]);
```

And the response window (in browser) has the following o/p

12 requests ❘ 987 KB transferred ❘ 710 ms (load: 651 ms, DOMContentLoaded: 640 ms)
HeadersPreviewResponseCookiesTiming

```
[{RowError:, RowState:2, Table:[{JobId:283499, JobStatus:Job Posted, RecruiterID:791,…},…],…},…]
0: {RowError:, RowState:2, Table:[{JobId:283499, JobStatus:Job Posted, RecruiterID:791,…},…],…}
HasErrors: false
**ItemArray: [283499**, Job Posted, 791, Technical Test Lead – Data Warehouse Testing, 1, 0, $, 50000, 80000, false,…]
RowError: ""
RowState: 2
Table: [{JobId:283499, JobStatus:Job Posted, RecruiterID:791,…},…]
**0: {JobId:283499,** JobStatus:Job Posted, RecruiterID:791,…}
**1: {JobId:283498**, JobStatus:Job Posted, RecruiterID:791,…}
1: {RowError:, RowState:2, Table:[{JobId:283499, JobStatus:Job Posted, RecruiterID:791,…},…],…}
HasErrors: false
**ItemArray: [283498**, Job Posted, 791, Technical Test Lead – Automation Testing using Ruby Cucumber, 1, 0, $,…]
RowError: ""
RowState: 2
Table: [{JobId:283499, JobStatus:Job Posted, RecruiterID:791,…},…]
**0: {JobId:283499**, JobStatus:Job Posted, RecruiterID:791,…}
**1: {JobId:283498**, JobStatus:Job Posted, RecruiterID:791,…}
```

=============
See job id's 283499,283498 each repeated 2 times in the result set even though data table has 2 rows only. Strange behaviour!

Comment: can you add your code please?

Comment: In order to obtain a useful answer, you must include the segment of code that causes the problem, and preferably a [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Edited and added code. Please check once

Comment: The way I called webapi method resulted into duplicated data. After reading some articles I've modified angular service and used $q and resolved the issue.  
Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I wonder what exactly your solution regarding the use of $q was. Would be great to know!